# Joomla 3 - Add css class to subcategories

Tags: joomla

I have a category blog that should display articles from all child categories of a given parent category.
E.G.  Parent-Category 
       -Child-Cat1 
       -Child-Cat2

All child categories are displayed, but I cannot style them individually, since they do not have a separate css-class.
Now I would like to wrap all child categories with a div and add a css-class with the corresponding title of the child category.

Can I do this with template overriding or something like that?

Cheers,

enne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes locate the appropriate component view file and duplicate in the templates html directory. Then you can apply any changes you wish without your changes getting whipped out every time you upgrade. http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core